# MVC4 Bundling and Minification with CDN

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, cdn, bundling-and-minification

I know the advantages of CDN and I also understand what benefits MVC4 Bundling and Minification offer.

I want to know that is it possible to combine the benefits of MVC4 Bundling and Minification and CDN. What I mean is that can we publish the bundled and minified script or css to a CDN and then in views we access the minified version through CDN url?

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is perfectly possibly and a good practice to publish the Minified script to your CDN. I routinely see both on various CDN's. This allows the developer to choose which version they need.

```
...then in views we access the minified version through CDN url?
```

Yes, you will access the minified version with the CDN url.

Comment: I am referring to the bundelling and minification feature of MVC that creates bundle of CSS and javascript files and minify them to reduce size.

Answer (score 0):

You can combine MVC4 Bundling and Minification with CDN

http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/bundling-and-minification

Code from the page above:

```
public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
{
    //bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
    //            "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js"));

    bundles.UseCdn = true;   //enable CDN support

    //add link to jquery on the CDN
    var jqueryCdnPath = "http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.7.1.min.js";

    bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery",
                jqueryCdnPath).Include(
                "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js"));

    // Code removed for clarity.
}
```

Comment: this appears to limit the number of files you can 'bundle' to 1. is that the case?